# Can I use mem_limit in docker-compose? and How?

Tags: docker, fig

mem_limit is supported by docker-compose? How can I test it?

I have a following **docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
repository:
  image: myregistry/my_nginx_image
  mem_limit: 60m
  volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
  ports:
    - "80:80"
```

How can I prove that the container actually does not exceed 60 mb of RAM?

I am using:

- docker 1.3.1
- docker-compose 1.1.0

Comment: yes, you can set mem_limit and cpu_shares http://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#working95dir-entrypoint-user-hostname-domainname-mem95limit-privileged-restart-stdin95open-tty-cpu95shares

Comment: `docker stats` allows to watch container resources.

Comment: Updated docs link: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources use `mem_limit` in compose file.

Comment: Be careful, `mem_limit` is DEPRECATED : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#mem_limit

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Yes. Memory limitation is supported by docker-compose and value can be set as in your example with "m" for megabytes.

It is possible to check what is the memory limit set for running Docker container using "docker stats" command.

If your container name is "repository_1" then use this command:

```
docker stats repository_1
```

The result of this will be simillar to this one:

```
CONTAINER       CPU %    MEM USAGE/LIMIT    MEM %     NET I/O
repository_1    1.93%    4.609 MiB/60 MiB   7.20%     1.832 KiB/648 B
```

Comment: I am using Docker 1.5. Apparently "docker stats" has been introduced in Docker 1.5:
https://blog.docker.com/2015/02/docker-1-5-ipv6-support-read-only-containers-stats-named-dockerfiles-and-more/

Comment: If you are using docker desktop on OSX you will also have to go into preferences and increase the memory limit above 2G or the mem_limit in docker is not honored.

Answer (score 10):

According to [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources), simple

```
mem_limit: 1000000000
```

should be enough. I guess, you should drop "m", and use bytes instead of megabytes.

Comment: Yes, I did that. Not getting any errors, but I'm not sure this delimiting the amount of memory to use. As I could check?

Comment: Link to compose docs talking about `mem_limit` and other options: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources

Comment: Be careful, `mem_limit` is DEPRECATED : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#mem_limit

Answer (score 4):

If you use docker compose v3 instead of:

```
mem_limit: 60m
```

you need to specify memory limit in `deploy` section:

```
deploy:
  resources:
    limits:
      memory: 60m
```

This change is described here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-2x-to-3x

Comment: Yes, but please keep in mind the following note from the same linked document: "deploy configuration only takes effect when using docker stack deploy, and is ignored by docker-compose"

Answer (score 1):

You can find how configure docker to limit resources (CPU & MEMORY) and how test your restrictions in this post written last year: [resource-management-in-docker](https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/09/11/resource-management-in-docker/#_example_managing_the_memory_shares_of_a_container).

Comment: another simple way to test MEMORY limits is running code inside containers  as follow: http://soichi.us/archives/11 but be careful with swap behavior as shown the reference of my answer.