# Limit JVM memory consumption in a Docker container

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

I've got a Spring Boot application implementing a service which I want to run in a Docker container. I've followed the guideline of the official [Spring docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) which suggest to create a DockerFile similar to this:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
ADD gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Then once the image is pushed to Docker I use [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to launch it this way:

```
  spring-boot-docker:
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    expose:
    - "80"
    image: my-repo/spring-boot-docker:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
    container_name: spring-boot-docker
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: '-Xmx64m'
```

Here I've got the `JAVA_OPTS` variable which limits the memory allocation, however, when I execute `docker stats spring-boot-docker`, the memory taken by the container is excessive (I understand the total memory taken by the JVM might be much more than 64M, but in this case is totally boundless).

I've also tried with the [`mem_limit` param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837544/can-i-use-mem-limit-in-docker-compose-and-how), but this slows down the application noticeably.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After struggling for a while, it seems the `JAVA_OPTS` variable can be passed to the container [when it's based in a Tomcat image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29926938/1199132), but Spring Boot uses Java itself as the base image.

I've found out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@cl4r1ty/docker-spring-boot-and-java-opts-ba381c818fa2#.ubbv3dcca) which solved the problem for me, just modifying the way the process is launched in the DockerFile and adding a JAVA_OPTS variable directly in the ENTRYPOINT:

```
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
```

This way, the JVM will pick the value from the command itself.

Comment: Please note that switching from the _exec_ to _shell_ form of `ENTRYPOINT` also has the side-effect of disabling {`CMD`, command line arguments} so running your container like `docker run <image> --spring.profiles.active=production` will just ignore the profile.