# How to define hostname into docker-compose.yml for MongoDB and Spring Boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create docker-compose.yml with MongoDB and Spring boot.
The problem is that I don't want to hardcode any database connections into the Spring's `application.properties`.

From [this article](https://success.docker.com/article/how-can-i-access-mongodb-container-from-another-container) I saw that you can start a mongodb container with predefined hostname.
As I understan all services defined into the compose yml file are in the same network but they has different ips, right?
**So the main question is how to define mongodb hostname into the docker-compose.yml and use that name into the spring boot application.properties file.**

I will try to give as much information as I can but if something is unclear let me know.

**Here is some information about the Spring Boot appication.**

Dependencies that I'm using into the spring project are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The appication has interfaces that extends MongoRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface ServiceLoggerRepository extends MongoRepository<ExampleEntity, String> {
}
```

and it is using @Document annotated entities

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "example")
public class ExampleEntity {

    @Id
    private String _id;
    private String name;
}
```

The database connection is defined into the application.properties file:

```
#here is the problem - this the vm ip
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://192.168.0.51 
spring.data.mongodb.database=mongo-test
```

**Information about the Spring Boot's Dockerfile:**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
COPY ./mongo-test.jar ./usr/mongo-test.jar
EXPOSE 8080
RUN sh -c 'touch /usr/mongo-test.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/mongo-test.jar"]
```

**Information about docker-compose:**
It has 2 services - MongoDB and Spring Boot application.

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongodb:
    restart: always
    image: mongo
    container_name: "mongodb-test"
    ports:
    - 27017:27017
    command: --smallfiles
  mongo-logger:
    restart: always
    build: ./mongo-test
    container_name: "mongo-test"
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
    - mongodb
    links:
    - mongodb
```

When the container is created and ran it works. But the problem is that I have no idea where and how define spring.data.mongodb.uri to use something static like `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongo-hostname` for example.

Is it possible and are there any king solutions or good practices for doing this?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057625/externalising-spring-boot-properties-when-deploying-to-docker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access to mongodb you need to use mongodb service name defined in `docker-compose.yml`.

And you can set that in application properties using env vars like below:

```
//aplication.properties
...
spring.data.mongodb.uri=${MONGODB_URI}
```

and

```
//docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: "mongodb-test"
    ports:
    - 27017:27017
  mongo-logger:
    build: ./mongo-test
    container_name: "mongo-test"
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    environment:
    - MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongodb
    depends_on:
    - mongodb
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what I needed :)