# Server Setup Spring Boot & Docker & Traefik

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm currently trying to set up a dockerized spring boot application on my server for a group project of my school, but I can't seem to figure out how to set it up so that the API (Spring Boot) is reachable over HTTPS. The client is a simple React Admin page, which works. It's only spring boot that I can't reach. The browser keeps telling me "you have been redirected too many times". The page is https://stocks-tracker-api.manuele-vaccari.ch/

The Spring Boot application is built with `./gradlew bootBuildImage --imageName=d3strukt0r/fhnw-stocks-tracker-api`

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    command:
      - --character-set-server=utf8mb4
      - --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - internal
      - traefik_proxy
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    environment:
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 100M
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true

      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTrackerPhpmyadmin0.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTrackerPhpmyadmin0.rule=Host(`${PHPMYADMIN_URL}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTrackerPhpmyadmin0.middlewares=to_https

      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTrackerPhpmyadmin.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTrackerPhpmyadmin.rule=Host(`${PHPMYADMIN_URL}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTrackerPhpmyadmin.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTrackerPhpmyadmin.tls.certresolver=le

  api:
    image: d3strukt0r/fhnw-stocks-tracker-api:nightly
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - internal
      - traefik_proxy
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    # volumes:
    #   - ./data/:/data/
    environment:
      # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057625/externalising-spring-boot-properties-when-deploying-to-docker
      # https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/datasource-configuration/
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
        "spring.datasource.url": "jdbc:mysql://db:3306/${DB_DATABASE}",
        "spring.datasource.username": "${DB_USERNAME}",
        "spring.datasource.password": "${DB_PASSWORD}",
        "spring.datasource.driver-class-name": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "spring.jpa.database-platform": "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect",
        "security.token.secret": "${API_TOKEN_SECRET}",
        "server.port": 8081
      }'
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true

      - traefik.http.services.stocks-tracker.loadbalancer.server.port=8081

      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTrackerApi0.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTrackerApi0.rule=Host(`${API_URL}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTrackerApi0.middlewares=to_https

      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTrackerApi.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTrackerApi.rule=Host(`${API_URL}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTrackerApi.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTrackerApi.tls.certresolver=le

  client:
    image: d3strukt0r/fhnw-stocks-tracker-client:nightly
    depends_on:
      - api
    networks:
      - internal
      - traefik_proxy
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true

      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTracker0.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTracker0.rule=Host(`${CLIENT_URL}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTracker0.middlewares=to_https

      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTracker.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTracker.rule=Host(`${CLIENT_URL}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTracker.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.stocksTracker.tls.certresolver=le

networks:
  internal:
    external: false
  traefik_proxy:
    external: true
```

Also for more information, here is the Traefik configuration

```
version: "2"

# Manage domain access to services
services:
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik
    command:
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=${ACME_EMAIL}
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=acme.json
      # - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.dnschallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.dnschallenge.provider=cloudflare
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443
      - --global.sendAnonymousUsage
      - --log.level=INFO
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=traefik_proxy
      - --pilot.token=${PILOT_TOKEN}
    restart: always
    networks:
      - traefik_proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
      # - ./acme-staging.json:/acme.json
    environment:
      CF_API_EMAIL: ${CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL}
      CF_API_KEY: ${CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY}
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true

      - traefik.http.routers.traefik0.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik0.rule=Host(`${TRAEFIK_URL}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik0.middlewares=to_https

      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`${TRAEFIK_URL}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik_auth
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal

      # Declaring the user list
      #
      # Note: all dollar signs in the hash need to be doubled for escaping.
      # To create user:password pair, it's possible to use this command:
      # echo $(htpasswd -nb user password) | sed -e s/\\$/\\$\\$/g
      - traefik.http.middlewares.traefik_auth.basicauth.users=${TRAEFIK_USERS}

      # Standard middleware for other containers to use
      - traefik.http.middlewares.to_https.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.to_https_perm.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.to_https_perm.redirectscheme.permanent=true

networks:
  traefik_proxy:
    external: true
```

What do I have to change for it to be reachable over HTTPS?

Comment: Do you run your System on an external Server or avpn or your local machine?

Comment: @AllesFuerDenDackel It's a local Ubuntu Server that i have. I have a guide I use to set it up https://gist.github.com/D3strukt0r/5aaba1a021d16b31fa19adf6eb26a102 the server is nothing fancy. should i maybe supply my traefik configuration?

Comment: Yes, the traegik config would be helpful. So the ubuntu server has a public ip address and you can get the required certificates?
Can you probife the traefik logs?

Comment: @AllesFuerDenDackel Yes i have multiple servers running on it without issues. I spend god knows how many hours to make work everything perfectly as it is now hahaha. Check the post. PS: I only need a docker-compose.yml to run docker, in case you are wondering.

Comment: @AllesFuerDenDackel I also want to add, for some reason, even after disabling the HTTPS redirect, it keeps redirecting me. And when I enable HTTPS, I get the unlimited redirects. This somehow sounds familiar to Nginx and PHP not passing the HTTPS status or something, but that's just a feeling