# Docker-Compose: Change JDBC from localhost to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, docker, jdbc

I am currently trying to find a unique solution for running my project locally and remotely on a CI-pipeline.
On git I got everything working by setting the bean dataSource url of the applicationContext.xml as shown in the following snipped:

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/project" />
    ...
</bean>
```

However, I was not able to configure my docker-compose file in a way that I can use the same url as shown previously. Instead it still requires the localhost `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project`

I guess I need to add some additional networking fields to my docker-compose file, so that I can use `jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/project` locally as well, but I could not figure it out by now.

My current docker-compose.yml to be modified:

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:9-jre11
    volumes:
      - ./target:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: mysql_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysql_password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql_database
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Running the project locally leads to the following error message if I use the mysql url instead of the local one:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql
```

Comment: Did you try host networking mode in compose? If your DB connects with the app outside docker, using host mode would be a good point to start troubleshooting.

Comment: The only thing you should need to do is set an environment variable for your Spring service, `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql`.  Does [Externalising Spring Boot properties when deploying to Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057625/externalising-spring-boot-properties-when-deploying-to-docker) describe your situation?

Comment: Good idea, but I guess something like SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL would only work for my ci pipeline. In this case i would need to overwrite the `jdbc:mysql://localhost` url for the git ci pipeline to the mysql one. However, the app is run over maven.

Comment: You need to use docker networks. https://docs.docker.com/network/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're starting your app locally outside of docker, is that correct?

In such case, not a perfect solution as you have to do it separately on each desktop, but you can add to your `/etc/hosts`, "mysql" host to localhost mapping:

```
127.0.0.1       mysql
```

Nevertheless, I recommend running your app over your `tomcat` docker image or having separate configuration for CI and local environments.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen sometimes,

Are you deploying in swarm mode?

Anyway the fix with in docker compose file for **single** node would look something like following.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:9-jre11
    volumes:
      - ./target:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
    - mynetwork

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: mysql_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysql_password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql_database
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
    - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
```

Specifically in swarm across **multiple** nodes:

```
docker network create mynetwork --driver overlay --attachable
```

compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:9-jre11
    volumes:
      - ./target:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
    - mynetwork

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: mysql_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysql_password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql_database
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
    - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    external: true
```