# java how externalise application.properties from my war file

Tags: java

I was asked to externalize my properties file from my wars file and gave a file an external path, because I have a docker image with a tomcat Inside and I was asked to master the files outside my docker.

how to do that?

I already know how to modify the pom to exclude my file from the build.

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057625/externalising-spring-boot-properties-when-deploying-to-docker)

Answer (score 1):

You can mount a volume in docker container to a path in host machine. Now when you create any application.properties file on host machine path, same will be visible and accessible to docker container as well.

Below is the plain `docker run` command to achieve it.

```
docker run -it --rm -v /home/k/myDocker:/k busybox sh
```

Below is the `docker-compose.yml` approach

```
version: '3'

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    volumes:
      - prometheus-data:/prometheus

volumes:
  prometheus-data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /disk1/prometheus-data
```