# docker : How to increase memory allocated to docker (Version: 17.12.0-ce)

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and somehow stuck with very less memory allocated to docker on my machine. The max limit it shows here is 15 mb. Can anyone suggest how to increase this limit ? do i have to uninstall and reinstall docker or there is some easy way to do that ?

I am using docker on win 10 in linux environment. The advanced setting doesnt show 2GB limit , it only shows the 15 mb limit which is too less for my computational requirement.

Any sort of help / guidance would be welcome please. Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question "[Docker windows container memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44145184/6309)" mentions the [`-m` option of `docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources).

Try that first:

```
-m, --memory=""
```

> Memory limit (format: `<number>[<unit>]`).
>   Number is a positive integer.
>   Unit can be one of b, k, m, or g. Minimum is 4M.

The OP reports using:

```
docker run --memory=4g
```

However:

- Docker for Windows through HyperV might limit a container memory to 1G anyway (see [issue 31604](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31604)).
- `docker run` requires an image name to run: see [`docker run` man page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#general-form).

Comment: "docker run" requires at least 1 argument

Comment: @OvaisJaffery You dod not mention that in your question. You did not mention the *exact* command you are running. Then I can debug its syntax.

Comment: docker run --memory=4g  where as my setting show that i have max 15 mb space allocated as resources :(

Comment: thanx for your responce  , i am using contained through following command : docker run -ti -v $(pwd):/home/fenics/shared quay.io/fenicsproject/stable:1.6.0       (Can you please suggest what exact command i must type to increase my memory limit to 1 gb

Comment: @OvaisJaffery That looks like a more complete command :) Did you add a `-m 1g` as an option, to see if the memory increases?

Comment: Waiting for your responce please

Comment: @OvaisJaffery Just add the option: `docker run -m 1g -it -v..`. etc.

Comment: @OvaisJaffery I just did.

Comment: i have used the command , the container has started but still mysettings advanced show the same 15 mb limit. How to check if the memory has really increased ?

Comment: @OvaisJaffery By doing some memory-intensive computation and see if you have an out-of-memory immediately or not.

Comment: See also https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/: use that on the container ID you see when you do a docker ps

Comment: @OvaisJaffery Or read: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-21-measure-your-docker-containers-resources

Comment: @OvaisJaffery read those links: they will show you what is allocated/used in term of memory

Comment: @OvaisJaffery Great! What did you change?

Comment: Nothing just restarted the container and checked stats.