# How to reduce default VM memory for Docker Linux containers on Windows

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-machine, hyper-v

### Scenario

- Windows 10 Professional
- Docker 18.06.1-ce running in Windows container mode
- 4GB of available memory on host system
- using Hyper-V virtual machine

### Problem

When trying to "switch to Linux containers" via Docker's taskbar item the process fails after a couple of seconds showing an error about "Not enough memory to start Docker".

[image: Not enough memory to start Docker]

Since the host system does not have that much memory, I'd like to reduce the maximum amount of memory the global Docker machine is allowed to use (I think 2 GB is the default here). Thus, I'd like to reduce that to just 1 GB.

When having Docker running in Windows container mode, there is no "advanced" section in Docker's settings that would allow to reduct that memory assignment easily.

[image: No "advanced" section in order to change memory assignment]

I was able to find the "MobyLinuxVM" using Windows' Hyper-V manager. However, when adjusting memory settings there, it is overwritten each time I start Docker and try again switching to Linux container mode.

[image: Hyper-V manager settings, that get overwritten again when starting Docker]

### Question

Is there a different way to define the maximum amount of memory for Docker without using the user interface (which won't work in this scenario due to the missing "advanced" section in Windows container mode - before being able to switch to Linux containers)?

Comment: install a simple linux vm instead ,  and then use docker on that

Comment: Are you talking about using e.g. VirtualBox to run Docker or is it something different?

Comment: use any virtulization tool to install linux VM with 1GB ram, then u can install docker  in there

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however that does not seem to be feasible since if would make volume sharing between host and guest systems much more difficult (since it has to be advertised to that intermediate Linux VM). Besides that it feels a bit like "VM inception" ;-)

Comment: Decreasing the memory allocation from Docker - Settings - Advanced settings from 2048 Mb to 1536 Mb did the job. Weird but it works!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After some searching I found out that settings of Docker's user interface are stored in `%APPDATA%\Docker\settings.json` (e.g. `C:\Users\olly\AppData\Roaming\Docker`), memory settings are defined in `memoryMiB` property.

The following solved the problem on my environement:

- quit Docker
- modify `settings.json` file using `notepad %APPDATA%\Docker\settings.json` in the run command prompt (`Windows-Key + R`)
- adjust value `memoryMiB` to `1024` (has been `2048` before)

  - in Docker versions 19.x and later the property is called `memoryMiB`
  - in Docker versions 18.x and before the property was called `VmMemory`
- save `settings.json`
- start Docker and finally being able to use "switch to Linux containers"

---

#### Property `memoryMiB` in Docker versions 19.x and later

[image: modify memoryMiB in settings.json]

#### Property `VmMemory` in Docker versions 18.x  and before

[image: modify VmMemory in settings.json]

Comment: Thanks Oliver Hader, I used your solution but couldn't see VmMemory so I tried changing memoryMiB to 1024 and that worked. Hope that helps others.

Comment: @Jambu Thx for the hint, I finally updated and adjusted the answer and screenshots for recent Docker versions