# ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon. You might need to start Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-10

I want to run Docker Compose on Windows 10. When I run `docker-compose up`, I get the following error message:

> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon. You might need to start Docker for Windows

I did not find a solution in the StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by lack of memory in my machine. The Docker Desktop was not starting since it was configured to run with 2 GB.

To solve my problem, I changed this parameter in `Settings -> Resources -> Memory`, reducing it to the minimum allowed: 1 GB. I also changed the swap value (`Settings -> Resources -> Swap`), setting the value to its minimum (512 MB).

Comment: There is no such option for me. I'm using docker desktop v `2.3.0.3 (45519)`

Comment: @AvtarNanrey These settings are accessible from the docker icon that stays in the taskbar (right side)... Maybe some answer in the following link can help you to set your memory size: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460770/docker-windows-container-memory-limit

Answer (score 1):

I have only seen this error when Docker Desktop is not currently running or it ran out of resources. Ensure that you have Docker Desktop installed and that it is running. Another possibility is that Docker is does not have enough resources to launch, so you will need to increase the resource limits. If this does not fix it, comment and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
# sudo docker-compose up
```

try adding `sudo`