# `supabase start` on Windows failing

Tags: docker, docker-compose, supabase, supabase-database

I am running Windows 11 and have installed the supabase cli via Scoop per the documentation. I am adding it to an existing repository so I have already ran the below commands with no issue:

```
supabase login
supabase init
```

When I go to run `supabase start` it fully installed the docker image and everything the first time, but it always ends with the below error message:

```
> supabase start
Database is not healthy.
Error: failed to connect to `host=localhost user=postgres database=postgres`: failed to receive message (unexpected EOF)
Try rerunning the command with --debug to troubleshoot the error.
```

I tried running with the `--debug` flag as instructed but I can't seem to tell any info from that and it fails with a different issue:

```
...                                                                                                        2023/03/11 22:46:09 Send Done
2023/03/11 22:46:09 Recv First Byte
2023/03/11 22:46:10 Sent Header: Host [docker]
2023/03/11 22:46:10 Sent Header: User-Agent [Go-http-client/1.1]
2023/03/11 22:46:10 Send Done
2023/03/11 22:46:10 Recv First Byte
Database is not healthy.
2023/03/11 22:46:11 Connect Start: tcp [::1]:54322
2023/03/11 22:46:11 Connect Done: tcp [::1]:54322
2023/03/11 22:46:11 PG Send: {"Type":"StartupMessage","ProtocolVersion":196608,"Parameters":{"database":"postgres","user":"postgres"}}
2023/03/11 22:46:13 Connect Start: tcp 127.0.0.1:54322
2023/03/11 22:46:13 Connect Done: tcp 127.0.0.1:54322
2023/03/11 22:46:13 PG Send: {"Type":"StartupMessage","ProtocolVersion":196608,"Parameters":{"database":"postgres","user":"postgres"}}
2023/03/11 22:46:15 Connect Start: tcp [::1]:54322
2023/03/11 22:46:15 Connect Done: tcp [::1]:54322
2023/03/11 22:46:15 PG Send: {"Type":"StartupMessage","ProtocolVersion":196608,"Parameters":{"database":"postgres","user":"postgres"}}
2023/03/11 22:46:17 Connect Start: tcp 127.0.0.1:54322
2023/03/11 22:46:17 Connect Done: tcp 127.0.0.1:54322
2023/03/11 22:46:17 PG Send: {"Type":"StartupMessage","ProtocolVersion":196608,"Parameters":{"database":"postgres","user":"postgres"}}
Error: failed to connect to `host=localhost user=postgres database=postgres`: failed to receive message (timeout: context deadline exceeded)
```

I am running with just the default config.toml from `supabase init`

Versions:

```
> docker --version
Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b
> docker-compose --version
Docker Compose version v2.15.1
> supabase -v
1.40.1
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the resolver e.g `--dns-resolver https`? 

Both errors appear related to being unable to connect with Postgres. Also, which is the docker image you are using?

Comment: So the 1st time I ran this it kept failing (hence the bounty). But whilst I get this Database is not healthy error still and on occasions it fails, it now succeeds more often than not and the connections are all healthy

Answer (score 3):

I only have superficial knowledge of `supabase` but, according to the symptoms you described, it seems that from time to time the `postgresql` container is unable to provide a health probe fast enough and that makes the `supabase start` command to fail.

The problem is especially of relevance the first time you issue `supabase start` because in that case the `postgresql` container should initialize the required database structures and associated stuff.

As stated for example in [this related Github issue](https://github.com/supabase/cli/issues/778) I think the problem could be very likely motivated by insufficient physical machine resources.

Unfortunately, AFAIK, `supabase` doesn't provide any flag or [configuration option](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/cli/config) for defining some type of timeout for controlling how long to wait for the health probes.

To solve the problem, you may try running the product using the `supabase start` [`--ignore-health-check` flag](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/cli/supabase-start):

```
supabase start --ignore-health-check
```

but probably the way to go should be vertical scaling your physical machine providing more resources, especially RAM memory. It running Windows 11 probably you will need to configure the [Docker for Windows memory limits](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/windows/#advanced): [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460770/docker-windows-container-memory-limit) could be of help regarding this configuration as well.