# Physical memory limitation in a Kubernetes Windows Container

Tags: kubernetes, windows-container

I have some Windows Containers running on Kubernetes with the following memory requests and limits set in the deployment yaml file:

```
      containers:
        - name: $$DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS$$$$APP_NAME$$
          image: $$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME$$:$$DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION$$
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: "1"
            limits:
              memory: "3Gi"
              cpu: "1.5"
```

However all of the pods get restarted when they reach 1GB consumption of memory.

I found another question stating that with docker, Windows Containers had memory constraints of 1GB when using Hyper-V Isolation Mode: [Docker windows container memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460770/docker-windows-container-memory-limit)

Is this also a thing for containers in kubernetes? Could there be any other reason why memory requests/limits are not applied for a Windows Container?

Observation: this project uses Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) and I do not have access to the settings in this layer.

Comment: How's the overall shape of the cluster, ie. is it generally short on resources or you have a lot of headroom on each node? How do you measure the 1G consumption?

Comment: Yes, there's a lot of headroom in the cluster. Each node (2 pods per node) has 16GB of physical memory, which results in about 12GB of allocatable memory. So each pod should be able to handle 3GB of RAM. The 1GB memory consumption has been observed in the kubernetes dashboard.

Comment: Note that in K8s (and AKS for consequence) you are using process isolation. You should be able to allocate more memory to the containers if the host has that available. Have you seen any logs from the container or host that help in investigating?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was that Visual Studio applied the default build configuration setting to my application, which is Any CPU - 32-bit preferred. This makes the build compatible with ARM.

I changed this to x64 and deployed the application to Kubernetes, then it was able to consume more than 1GiB of RAM. My initial thought was that this would not solve the problem, because 32-bit .NET applications should be able to consume 2GB of RAM, but in the end, it was the cause of the problem.